# using await inline on variable in outer scope

Tags: javascript, scope, async-await

```
(async function iife () {
  const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
  let count = 0
  async function returnNumberAsync (number) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(number), 0)
    })
  }
  await Promise.all(numbers.map(async number => {
    count += await returnNumberAsync(number)
  }))
  console.log(count)
})()
```

This snippet logs `4` to the console, which is completely beyond me. As soon as I assign the promised value inside `map` to its own local variable …

```
const result = await returnNumberAsync(number)
count += result;
```

… it logs `10` like I'd expect. What's happening when I `count += await …`??

Comment: Why would it be 10?

Comment: @zer00ne cause 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 *is* 10 ?

Comment: You are starting multiple promises and passing an asynchronous callback, thus all of them gets called before the first one executes, thus all of them getting count = 0 and hence the final result is 4;

Comment: With `Promise.all()` it feels lateral so I didn't expect 10

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do `count += await <expression>`, the initial value of `count` to be added to the resolve value is saved *before* the `await` part is resolved. So

```
count += await returnNumberAsync(number)
```

is like

```
count = count + await returnNumberAsync(number)
```

as you can see:

```js
(async function iife () {
  const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
  let count = 0
  async function returnNumberAsync (number) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(number), 0)
    })
  }
  await Promise.all(numbers.map(async number => {
    count = count + await returnNumberAsync(number)
  }))
  console.log(count)
})()
```

In each of the 4 closures, `count` is seen to be 0 before the `await`s resolve, so only in the final `await` microtask, where it resolves to

```
count += await returnNumberAsync(4)
// or
count = 0 + await returnNumberAsync(4)
// or
count = 4
```

does `4` get assigned to `count`. The fact that other numbers were assigned to `count` earlier is ignored. They did happen, but the assignment of the final iteration is all you see with the current code.

Comment: Thats really a hidden pitfall (yay, concurrency in a single threaded language) ... `count = await fn() + count;` would also work

Comment: Ok, so the assignment of `count` happens before the function is interrupted, as it's placed left of the `await`. And if it's put right (or below) the `await`, everything's fine. Makes sense, but quite a pitfall nonetheless. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You should always try to avoid mutating a shared state from within asynchronous code. If your operations are not atomic (`count += await` is not atomic as it reads `count`, waits for the asynchronous task, then writes to `count` (and `count` might have changed in the meantime)) that can get you into trouble.

Your code can easily be modified to not use a shared state:

```
 const count = (await Promise.all(numbers.map(returnNumberAsync))).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be more clear what is happening if you rewrite the `async/await` inside the `map()` to `.then`.

```js
function returnNumberAsync(number) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(number), 0);
  });
}

(async function iife() {
  const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  let count = 0;

  await Promise.all(
    numbers.map(number =>
      Promise.resolve(count).then(temp =>
        returnNumberAsync(number).then(res => {
          count = temp + res;
        })
      )
    )
  );
  console.log(count);
})();
```