# Why is awaiting inline on a variable in the outer scope different from simple await assignment?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

Before I asked this question, I did research [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56271938/using-await-inline-on-variable-in-outer-scope).

I don't understand why in the examples below the output is different in `run1` and `run2`.

```js
"use strict";

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(ms);
    }, ms)
  );
}

const seconds = [1000, 3000, 2000];

let output1 = 0;
let output2 = 0;

console.log("start");

(async function run1() {
  await Promise.all(
    seconds.map(async sec => {
      output1 = output1 + (await sleep(sec));
    })
  );
  console.log({ output1 });
})();

(async function run2() {
  await Promise.all(
    seconds.map(async sec => {
      const res = await sleep(sec);
      output2 = output2 + res;
    })
  );
  console.log({ output2 });
})();

console.log("fin");
```

Comment: Good question. They should be the same

Comment: But it's still a duplicate of [the question mentioned by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56271938/using-await-inline-on-variable-in-outer-scope), no? At least I don't see the difference

Comment: @A_A, I want to know why `run1` and `run2` have different outputs. The duplicated question answer how `run1` works but why `run2` doesn't work as `run1`?

Comment: just to say it's not encouraged to [ask exactly same question just because it's closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69009288/why-async-await-have-different-output-when-await-expression-is-a-argument-of-con) (and also answered)

Comment: I like questions like that. Cool Dude that you ask it! The answer below is also very good. The answer below also explains it well. Another lesson learned.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why async/await have different output when await expression is a argument of concat()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69009288/why-async-await-have-different-output-when-await-expression-is-a-argument-of-con)

Comment: @traktor, No. that's why I clarify my question and ask here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first case (output1), the current value of `output1` is "cached" before calling and evaluating the async function and awaiting it.

It would be more or less equivalent to the following (order of execution follows the sleep time of each async function):

```
let old = output1; // 0
output1 = old + 1000;
output1 = old + 2000;
output1 = old + 3000; // 0 + 3000 is the final result
```

For the second case (output2), the async function is evaluated *before* the current value of `output2` is cached. You end up with a sum of all values.

It is more or less equivalent to:

```
let old = output2; // 0
output2 = old + 1000;
old = output2; // 1000
output2 = old + 2000;
old = output2; // 3000
output2 = old + 3000; // 3000 + 3000 is the final result
```

Note: if you use the values [1000, 4000, 2000], you will see that the result is 4000, so only the middle value is added to the output (not 1000+2000 which would also be 3000 with the values from the question)

To be honest, I would have expected the result in the first case to be either 2000 (the last value) or non-deterministic (race-conditions). Apparently, there is some little detail in how JavaScript schedules each async task.

Thanks to [A_A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6548154/a-a) with an answer to why the final result is 3000 (or 4000, with updated values): this is the longest delay and it will be executed/finished last.

---

Additional explanation: there seems to be confusion caused by my bad word choice of "cached". Let me try to explain:

JavaScript programs are generally evaluated top-to-bottom, left-to-right (ignoring async calls for a moment).

```
let y = 6;
let x = 7;
y = y * x;
```

Will be "seen" by the JavaScript runtime as:

1. Store 6 in y
2. Store 7 in x
3. Remember current y value (6)
4. Remember current x value (7)
5. Multiply 6 and 7 (= 42)
6. Store 42 in y

Let's map this to your first example:

```
for (let i of [100,300,200])
   output1 = output1 + (await sleep(i));
```

1. Remember current output1 value (0)
2. Start first async "sleep" task and await its completion
3. Remember current output1 value (0)
4. Start second async sleep task and await its completion
5. Remember current output1 value (0)
6. Start third async sleep task and await its completion
7. First sleep task completes (100)
8. Add current output1 value and task result (0 + 100)
9. Store result in output1 (100)
10. Third sleep task completes (200)
11. Add current output1 value and task result (0 + 200)
12. Store result in output1 (200)
13. Second sleep task completes (300)
14. Add current output1 value and task result (0 + 300)
15. Store result in output1 (300)
16. The final value of `output1` is 300

Now compare to the second example. The evaluation order becomes:

```
for (let i of [100,300,200]) {
  const res = await sleep(sec);
  output2 = output2 + res;
}
```

1. Start first async "sleep" task and await its completion
2. Start second async sleep task and await its completion
3. Start third async sleep task and await its completion
4. First sleep task completes (100)
5. Remember current output2 value (0)
6. Add current output2 value and task result (0 + 100)
7. Store result in output2 (100)
8. Third sleep task completes (200)
9. Remember current output2 value (100)
10. Add current output2 value and task result (100 + 200)
11. Store result in output2 (300)
12. Second sleep task completes (300)
13. Remember current output2 value (300)
14. Add current output2 value and task result (300 + 300)
15. Store result in output2 (600)
16. The final value of `output2`  is 600

Comment: I guess the value is 3000, because there it waits 3000ms and hence it is the last assignment that takes place. The other assignments are already finished after 1000ms and 2000ms, and thus overriden

Comment: A_A: yes, you are right! That's the answer!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I know why `the current value of output1 is "cached" before calling and evaluating the async function` and why `output2` didn't cached like `output1`?

Comment: @ikhvjs because for `output2`, `res = await sleep(sec)` is guaranteed to be complete before `output2 += res` is called. In the first case, the async task is only started _after_ the current value has already been cached: `output1 = output1 /*CACHE HERE!*/ + (await sleep(sec));`

Comment: @ef-dknittl-frank, Thanks for the comment, but why for `output2 = output2 + res`, the `output2 on the right hand side of = sign` didn't cached the original `0` instead of cached the updated one?

Comment: @ikhvjs because the `await` statement is awaiting BEFORE the assignment expression. Reading the current value happens _after_ the async call has completed. For case 1, the async call starts AFTER the current value has already been read.

Comment: On a side note: `output1 = (await sleep(sec)) + output1;` should work like output2. The expression `x + y` is evaluated from left to the right, therefore it first waits for `await sleep(sec)` and afterwards takes the `output1` value. For me, I see it as "evaluating the expression from left to right" rather than "caching", but it's the same effect

Comment: @ef-dknittl-frank, Thanks for your comment. I also answer what I understand. You can have a look.

Comment: Also, what you mean cached is actually [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Comment: No, what I meant by cached is "evaluated"/"reading the current value pointed to by the variable". See my edit with a step-by-step execution plan

Comment: @ef-dknittl-frank, I did see your last example,  `Remember current output2 value` and this is because of `Closure`...